# Condition on k to have a Symmetric Positive Definite Matrices

Tags: matrices

Consider the matrix

$$M =\begin{bmatrix}
    k & 0 & 0&\\
    1 & k & 0\\
    0 & 0 & k\end{bmatrix}$$

with $k \geq 0$ given and $A=MM'$ ( $M'=M$ transposed)

For which values of $k$, $A$ is a symmetric Positive definite matrix ?

First, $A$ has to be symmetric, $(MM')'=MM'$

Then for $x\neq 0$ , $x'A x > 0$.

I calculated $x'A x$ and I got : $x=\begin{bmatrix} x_a \\ x_b \\ x_c \end{bmatrix}$

$$x'A x = k^2 x_a^2+2 k x_a x_b+2 k x_c x_a+x_b^2+2 x_b x_c+k^2x_b^2+x_c^2+2 k x_b x_c+k^2x_c^2$$

I tried to write it as

$$ (x_a + x_c)^2 +(x_a + k x_b)^2+(k x_a + x_c)^2 + (k x_c + x_b)^2 - x_a^2 - x_b^2 - x_c^2$$

and then i'm stuck I don't know how it helps me to find $k$ for which $x' A x$ is positive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\det(M)=\det(M')=k^3$$

If $k=0$, then $\det(M)=0$,  hence $M'$ is singular. Hence we can find $x \neq 0$ such that $M'x=0$ and we end up with $x'Ax=0$.

If $k \neq 0$, then $\det(M) \neq 0$, hence $M'$ is nonsingular. Hence for $x \neq 0$,

$$x'Ax=x'MM'x=\left\| M'x\right\|^2>0$$